Gganimate with ggplot: legend is not shown
So I have this script and the animation just works fine, but I can not get the legend/guide. With the static map the legend appears automatically.
Here is the code for the animated plot:
alapadatok <- attendance

alapadatok <- alapadatok %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(., "n.a.")))

alapadatok <- alapadatok %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("c") | contains("/"), as.numeric))

capacity_long <- alapadatok %>%
  select(League, starts_with("c")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("c"), 
               names_to = "Season", 
               values_to = "Capacity")

capacity_long$Capacity <- as.numeric(as.character(capacity_long$Capacity))

map_data <- map_data("world")

# Filter map data to include only relevant countries
map_data_filtered <- map_data %>%
  filter(region %in% alapadatok$League)

# Merge the map data with capacity_long
map_merged <- map_data_filtered %>%
  left_join(capacity_long, by = c("region" = "League"))

animated_map <- ggplot(data = map_merged, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Capacity)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", show.legend = TRUE) +  # Borders of the countries
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "lightblue", high = "blue", na.value = "grey", name = "Capacity") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "middle") +
  labs(title = 'Map of Capacity in Season: {closest_state}') +
  transition_states(Season, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1, wrap = FALSE)

# Animate the plot
anim <- animate(animated_map, nframes = 400, fps = 20, width = 800, height = 600)

# Save the animation
anim_save("capacity_map_animation.gif", animation = anim)

# To preview in RStudio
anim

And here is the one for the static plot:
ggplot(data = map_merged, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Capacity)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black") +  # Borders of countries
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "blue", name = "Capacity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +  # Try 'right', 'bottom', or specific coordinates
  labs(title = 'Map of Capacity') 

I tried it with scale_fill_gradient() and scale_fill_continous, it worked with both but could not get the legend with neither of them. Also tries to add guides(fill = guide_colorbar()), but then it runs but nothing shows up in the viewer.
What could be the problem?

We don't have data like yours so we can't run this. Can you replicate the problem with a standard data set, or include sample data (e.g. with dput()) so it runs?

"middle" is not an allowed value for legend.position, is it? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html
